# what is expiration headers for CSS, JS, and Images?

Tags: css, caching

After analyzing  my website with pagespeed(addon for firefox), I got mydomain.com/css/common.css (expiration not specified) . What is this means ? How would I give the expiration?

Comment: Google? You can set headers using htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

**Expiration header:**

It is duration or time for your CSS, images & JS to be cached. Its means you decide the expiry date of all your CSS, JS & images. Browser will look for the content after expiry time or if you delete all your browser cache. If you are hosting on Amazon tools like Cloudberry gives you option to add expire headers.